# Copying file path from GUI to the command line (another question)

Tags: gnome-terminal, clipboard, copy-and-paste

I used to get the path to some files by selecting them with the mouse and then copying and pasting them into my terminal. Howerver, this doesn't work anymore.

I realize that the subject have been exposed several times; however, I cannot figure out what the solution to my own case is.

Any suggestion on how to restore this would be appreciated.

```
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
64-bit
GNOME Version 42.5
Windowing System X11
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to copy paste into terminal is copy the file path (as you are doing now) and then paste using <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+V</kbd>

I also tried it with a right mouse click and Paste which worked.

Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't need to past to the terminal in particular but anywhere else, such as in a text document.

Comment: Ctrl+V works just fine in LO Writer